# AdMob android playstore release with Test ID's?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, admob, ads

I don't quite understand the logic behind this, first I have to release my app and then AdMob will check my app to allow ads.

So I have to release a version with test Ad-Id's to the playstore and while AdMob will check my app, people will download and use my App with the test Ads and in theory if they will never update my app, they will forever see test Ads?

Or do I have to create the mediation groups, add the ID's to my app and then release the app and tell AdMob to check it? So people will see "blanks" where the banner ads are supposed to be while AdMob is still checking my app?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that AdMob can already approve the real ad id's while my app is not released so for anybody else who is wondering, just wait a few days and you will be able to use your custom ad id's automatically in your internal test application.